# Придаточное. Что подлежащее, а что дополнение?

Tags: подлежащее, местоимение, порядок-слов, дополнение, придаточное-предложение

"последствия, которые вызвали твои действия"

По смыслу понятно, что местоимение "которые" является дополнением (действия вызвали последствия). Но, с грамматической точки зрения, поскольку винительный и именительный падежи имеют в данном случае одинаковую форму, может возникнуть и другое понимание: последствия вызвали действия.

То же самое и здесь:
«Все эти мотивы крутятся вокруг достижения синергетического эффекта, который дает увеличение активов компании»

Придаточное также создаёт замешательство для человека, не разбирающегося в теме: что же здесь является подлежащим, а что — дополнением. Т.е увеличение активов дает синергетический эффект, или наоборот — синергетический эффект дает увеличение активов.
И вообще, можно ли местоимение "который" в именительном падеже использовать не в роли подлежащего, а в роли дополнения (делать инверсию), если по контексту понятно, что это дополнение?
Кстати, даже если абстрагироваться от местоимения "который", то предложение "Синергетический эффект дает увеличение активов" также может восприниматься двояко — как прямой порядок слов, так и как инверсия с дополнением на первом месте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать КОТОРЫЙ в качестве дополнения, конечно, можно: *На обед будет борщ, который отлично готовит мама.* Такого рода предложения ни у кого не вызывают сомнений, ибо всё предельно ясно.

Другое дело предложения типа *Я вижу автобус, который обогнал трамвай.* Непонятно, автобус двигался быстрее или трамвай. Неясность устраняется только путём создания синтаксического синонима. Предложение перестраиваем.

В Ваших примерах двусмысленность очевидна, поэтому выражения требуют правки: *последствия, вызванные твоими действиями; эффекта, достигаемого (достижимого) увеличением активов компании.*

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете тест, то подобной неоднозначности следует избегать. Если речь идет о понимании уже написанного, то предпочтение обычно отдается прямому порядку слов и тому "кандидату", который стоит ближе к зависимому слову: "последствия, которые", "эффекта, который".

Comment: То есть предпочтение отдаётся роли подлежащего?

Comment: Да, я думаю, что, "расшифровывая" подобные предложения при отсутствии всяких "намеков", нужно отдать предпочтение прямому порядку слов, а в этом случае слово *который* является подлежащим. "Автобус, который обогнал трамвай" -> автобус двигался быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Было бы проще анализировать полное предложение, например:

```
Животные, которые родились в зоопарке, не приспособлены к жизни в дикой природе.
```

Вот [тут](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/737-221_pridatochnye_opredelitelnye.html) можно найти ещё примерчик:

```
Давайте помечтаем, например, о той жизни, какая будет после нас, лет через двести-триста.
```

В первом примере подлежащим подчинённого предложения является "которые", а во втором -- "какая".