# О двусмысленных предложениях

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

О двусмысленных предложениях типа "Автобус обогнал трамвай" мы уже не раз говорили (например, [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436682/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/436686#436686)). Но вот в новостях на Первом канале на экране  я увидел текст, кторый нашел потом на сайте [Коммерсанта](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/3720971):

**Прибор, в котором произошло замыкание, должен был отключить защитный автомат.**

Мне не сразу удалось понять, "кто кого" должен был отключить. Причем со слов диктора я понял, что это цитата из отчета, составленного экспертной комиссией. Таким образом, фраза, скорее всего, была проверена и членами комиссии, и редакторами новостей. Может, я просто придираюсь?

Answer (score 2):

*Технические* эксперты не всегда владеют языком в должной степени. Эта фраза неудачна, но в их среде она была бы понята однозначно: не сработало автоматическое защитное устройство. Возможно, за этим пониманием и осталась незамеченной грамматическая двусмысленность. Но меня не удивило бы, если на самом деле это был *пересказ* от составителей материала для диктора.

Answer (score 2):

**Прибор, в котором произошло замыкание, должен был тут же отключить защитный автомат, однако тот оказался неисправным.**

Защитное устройство не сработало, это факт, но мне и сейчас непонятно, "кто кого" должен был отключить.

**Я так понимаю  "физику" процесса.** Если в приборе произошло короткое замыкание, то в цепи увеличивается ток, что приводит к отключению питающего автомата. По крайней мере, в квартирах так всё происходит, на щитке подписаны все потребители электрической энергии, у каждого свой автомат Поэтому прибор должен был "выключить" автомат, а это привело бы к отключению прибора от питания.

Судя по построению фразы, автор хотел, **как мне кажется**, сказать, что прибор "должен был отключить защитный автомат", а не наоборот, хотя я думаю, **что это не очень грамотно с точки зрения электротехники.**

**Надо было написать так:**

Пожар начался в светодиодном светильнике, который залила талая вода с крыши. Это привело короткому замыканию, а защитный автомат, который  в этом случае должен был отключить  прибор, оказался неисправным.

Comment: Думаю, корректно говорить, что защитный автомат не отключается (перестает работать), а срабатывает, его работа - отключить питание прибора. Сам же автомат остается подключенным к сети все время, он работает как выключатель.

Comment: Наверное, защитный автомат выключается, а прибор отключается. Ведь автомат мы можем выключить и вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы придираетесь. **На опушке рос огромный дуб. [...] И этот самый дуб свалил ураган.** Разве непонятно? Так здесь то же самое.

Comment: Я бы так не писал. Как читателю, мне не удается понять такие фразы с первого раза. После первого прочтения "слева направо" обнаруживается, что логика нарушена, приходится обдумывать фразу еще раз. Не знаю, есть ли формальные правила или рекомендации не использовать такие фразы, но надеюсь, что есть.